# Empty Textbox and DateTime Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, textbox, null

I have a textbox that represents a date and I want to parse it to a
**DateTime**, but sometimes this **textBox** can be empty string and I want to send
it to the **DataBase** as null or as empty Date, how can I do it?  I am using a webservice and I thought the following would pass a null:

```
txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text != string.Empty ? DateTime.Parse(txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text) : DateTime.MinValue,
```

but it returns the

```
"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."
```

ASP.NET and c# code below:

```
protected void cmdSaveCreateNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShortSaleInvestorReviewServiceClient _service = new ShortSaleInvestorReviewServiceClient();
    int createApp;

    createApp = _service.AddNote("10002",txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text != string.Empty ? DateTime.Parse(txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text) : DateTime.MinValue, 2, txtNoteCreateNote.Text); //Created by ID 
}
```

Comment: What about .length, instead of empty?  May work.

Comment: Change the data type of that column to varchar and allow it as null. Not a friendly advice but may work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attempted to pass the DateTime.MinValue, 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, which is a common technique. You discovered, however, that SQL Server datetime type does not like dates prior 1753.

DateTime is a structure and cannot be null. However, a nullable version is available. You can declare it like so...

```
DateTime? anullableDateTime;
```

If the .AddNote method has a nullable DateTime parameter, you are all set.  Just set a null like so...

```
txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text != string.Empty ? DateTime.Parse(txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text) : null
```

If not, decide on a minimum date you will treat as null in your UI.  1/1/1900 is a favorite, and do this...

```
 txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text != string.Empty ? DateTime.Parse(txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text) : new DateTime(1900,1,1)
```

Just set your textbox.Text = null when you retrieve this value. Saving a real date has the added advantage of not having to deal with nulls in your database queries.

Comment: Might need to change `null` to `(DateTime?)null`

Answer (score 1):

Try This One

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(txtCommentDateCreateNote.Text);
```